# Delete from SQL table if there are Duplicates AND if duplicates are older than 30 days

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write an SQL query to access a Microsoft SQL table. What I am hoping to accomplish is that I can find all rows that have duplicates and delete duplicates only if they are older than 30 days. Here is an example table:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]
    (id1, id2, firstName, lastName, dayTime) 
VALUES
    (12, 13, 'Syed','Abbas','05-02-2023'),
    (12, 13, 'Syed','Abbas','07-02-2023'),
    (12, 14, 'Adam', 'Johnson', '07-02-2023'),
    (10, 9, 'Monique', 'Brown', '03-03-2023')
```

And this is what I have written for my query:

```
    DELETE T
FROM
(
SELECT *
, DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY id1, id2
              ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
            )
FROM [dbo].[test]
) AS T
WHERE DupRank > 1 and dayTime < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

The outcome I am *trying* to get is that only row 1 (12, 13, Syed, Abbas, 05-02-2023) will be deleted and the rest of the values will stay. However, when I run this query, it does not delete anything-- no errors, just 0 rows affected.

I have tried the separate parts of the query and they work fine (ie, when I just delete duplicates, it removes row 2, and when I just delete for older than 30 days, it removes rows 1 and 4). I am not sure if I am using the "and" clause incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing (although it's hard to say without seeing the query plan) that the non-deterministic `ORDER BY` is causing problems.

When you write `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` that means that the server is free to calculate the row-number in any order. So it could be that the *older* row is being numbered 1 and the newer row 2. Then when you filter to `DupRank > 1 and dayTime < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())` you are filtering out both rows.

So just use a deterministic numbering. The logical thing to do here would be to number from newest to oldest, so that you always keep the newest row and any others which are less than 30 days old.

```sql
DELETE T
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
      DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY T.id1, T.id2
                ORDER BY T.dayTime DESC)
    FROM dbo.test T
) AS T
WHERE T.DupRank > 1
  AND T.dayTime < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
```